# JavaScript function with parameters in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I want something like this:

```
function goTo (String string)
{
    window.location.href = string;
}
```

and access it with button click.. like:

```html
<button class="button" onClick="home(" My target url/file directory ")">Test</button>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: What did you try an why didn't it work?

Comment: the code example  you provide is not even valid javascript. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code

Answer (score 2):

You can't have double quotes inside double quotes, use single quotes instead:

```
<button class="button" onClick="home(' My target url/file directory ')">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right path:

```js
function goTo(url) {
  window.location.href = url;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="goTo('http://www.stackoverflow.com')">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, just that you need to tweak your code a little bit, [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/hjq7fzj6/)

Function arguments doesn't need a type

```
function goTo ( string)
{
    window.location.href = string;
}
```

Finally, you need to escape inner double quotes

```
<button class="button" onClick="goTo ('My target url/file directory')">Test</button>
```

Comment: This will not work, to have double quotes inside html attribute you will need to use html entities.

Comment: @jcubic you are right, updated code. However, it looks a lot similar to your now :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I got it working this way:

```
function locationUrl (string) {
    window.location.href = string;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" onClick="locationUrl(&quot;#&quot;)">Test</button>
```

Thanks to you all!